# The script does not work when adding a class using jQuery addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found a script which detects the file type in jQuery:

```js
$(function(){
    jQuery.fn.LiFileType = function(options){
    var options = jQuery.extend({
        //gh: 25 //Высота пунктов меню
    },options);
    return this.each(function(index) {
        var loadFile = $(this);
        var file = loadFile.attr('href')
        var reWin = /.*\\(.*)/;
        var fileTitle = file.replace(reWin, "$1"); //выдираем название файла для w*s
        reUnix = /.*\/(.*)/;
        var fileTitle = fileTitle.replace(reUnix, "$1"); //выдираем название для *nix
        var RegExExt =/.*\.(.*)/;
        var extPre = fileTitle.replace(RegExExt, "$1");//и его расширение
        ext = extPre.substr(0,3)
        var pos;
        if (ext){
            switch (ext.toLowerCase())
            {
                case 'doc': pos = '(DOC)'; break;
    case 'bmp': pos = '(BMP)'; break;                       
    case 'jpg': pos = '(JPG)'; break;
    case 'jpeg': pos = '(JPEG)'; break;
    case 'mp3': pos = '(MP3)'; break;
    case 'avi': pos = '(AVI)'; break;
    case 'wmv': pos = '(WMV)'; break;
    case 'flv': pos = '(FLV)'; break;
    case 'pdf': pos = '(PDF)'; break;
    case 'txt': pos = '(TXT)'; break;
    case 'xls': pos = '(XLS)'; break;
    case 'rar': pos = '(RAR)'; break;
    case 'zip': pos = '(ZIP)'; break;
    default   : pos = ''  ; break;
            };
            // Создаем специальный класс для нового класса
        var cssRuleClass = 'filIcon_' + index;
        $(this).addClass(cssRuleClass);
        var cssRule = '.' + cssRuleClass + ':after{ content:\" '+pos+'\";}';
        $('<style>').text(cssRule).appendTo('head');
        };
    });
};
    $(".filetype").LiFileType();
    
    //layout js
    $('.filetype').click(function(){return false;});
})
```

```css
.fileIcon:after {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="file.doc" class="filetype" >file.doc</a>
<a href="file.bmp" >file.bmp</a>
<a href="file.jpg">file.jpg</a>
<a href="file.jpeg">file.jpeg</a>
<a href="file.png">file.png</a>
<a href="file.gif">file.gif</a>
<a href="file.psd">file.psd</a>
<a href="file.mp3">file.mp3</a>
<a href="file.wav">file.wav</a>
<a href="file.ogg">file.ogg</a>
<a href="file.avi">file.avi</a>
<a href="file.wmv">file.wmv</a>
<a href="file.flv">file.flv</a>
<a href="file.pdf">file.pdf</a>
<a href="file.exe">file.exe</a>
<a href="file.txt">file.txt</a>
<a href="file.xls">file.xls</a>
<a href="file.rar">file.rar</a>
<a href="file.zip">file.zip</a>
```

Everything works fine only when I class `filetype` write with hands for links... but when I add `$('a').addClass('filetype');` gives me error of `jquery.LiFileType.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

what could be the problem? already 2 days looking for a solution :(

**UPD**
Maybe try this effect with `span`? 
For Example add the array and display him wrap over the tag `a`:

```
var fileIcon = $( "a" ).wrap( "<span class='another'></div>" );
```

and to add a pseudo-class after?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem seems to be here:

```
var fileTitle = file.replace(reWin, "$1"); //выдираем название файла для w*s
reUnix = /.*\/(.*)/;
var fileTitle = fileTitle.replace(reUnix, "$1"); //выдираем название для *nix
```

Remove the var before your second fileTitle and try it again

Comment: nothing has changed :(
I updated the question, show please;

Comment: But the error you posted says that it occurs on line 10 of your function, which is at your second fileTitle. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Yes still get... I don't know why

Comment: Dumb question: Did you press ctrl+f5 in your browser to refresh the script?

Comment: Focki, of course... the script works without the var for you?

Comment: yes https://jsfiddle.net/jkwxxqgr/
but what i see now is that u never add the class to the other links in this script

Comment: amazing, it works in jsfiddle but not working on the website.. the error remains

Comment: have you tried to call the .addClass and $(".filetype").LiFileType(); inside $(document).ready(function() {
//do work
})
maybe jquery cant find the class because html has not finished rendering

Comment: Nope, didn't help this :(

Comment: i still cant imagine how the error occurs at the second line with fileTitle if you have removed the var before. Because you already used the replace on it in this line and when there is something undefined it has to be one of the variables loadfile or file. As the string replace function doesnt return undefined